# Expose sql database as a web service for access from android phone

Tags: .net, android, web-services

I have created two EditText fields and a single submit button in Android using Eclipse. Now I need to develop a web service preferably in .NET that would expose my database. I must say that I did see this [http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx] before posting but I do not have knowledge of how to use a WCF service and instead I would prefer REST or SOAP.

I now just need to call the webservice on click of a button that would get a list of values of a particular column of the database in a ListView with a checkbox on emulator of Android

Please can anyone tell me how should I go about doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Given your note below, I would skip the "...synchronize an SQLiteDatabase..." part of the background service on Android (as there doesn't seem to be anything to synchronize or cache on the target Android device). I would make that background service directly call your web service.

The important thing here is to perform the actual HTTP-request from your Android application in a *worker thread*. If you call it from the UI-thread (a.k.a. the default- or main thread) the web service will most likely not answer quickly enough to keep the application alive and Android will treat it as a non-responsive application.

An Android `Service` will by default run in the same thread as the caller runs in (which most likely is the UI-thread). You could have a look at [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which manages all the threading for you.

But before all this I think you need to design your database and sort out your web service. Unfortunately I'm a bit too rusty on Microsoft's products in order to provide you with useful help. But I figure there must be tons of tutorials and "how-to"'s out there.

**ORIGIN:**

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) has a suprizingly good definition of what REST should be about. This concept also maps very well to the [Android `ContentProvider`'s concept](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Assuming that you want to expose a database on a web server I think I would write a simple REST based web service (on your web server) which gives you access to the tables and columns needed by the app (no more, no less).

By default I would perhaps continue with writing a background service (on Android) that periodically would synchronize an SQLiteDatabase (still on Android), maybe through a ContentProvider (NOTE that `ContentProviders` aren't the only way to communicate with a database, actually I would even say that communicating with a database isn't even the main feature of a `ContentProvider`).

Finally I would broadcast a notification (still on Android) when the synchronization ends so that any (Android) clients would know when to automatically request fresh data from the SQLite database. Perhaps this fetching of fresh data could also be triggered by pressing a button in the UI in order to allow the user to trigger a manual update as well.

If you write more about your Android App and what it's supposed to achieve I will modify my answer to be more correct and specific.

Comment: Ok here's what my Android app is going to do : 1) Ask the user to enter two values in those Edittext fields and then press submit button . The java file for which I have already created in Android ,coz it's easy 2) On clicking on submit button I need to call a web service created in .NET (either REST or SOAP anything will do ) in such a manner that it will give all entries of a particular column of my database table ...So now i just want someone to tell me how do I first create my own SQL database in VS2008 , write the code to expose it and again write a code for Android to call it .u got it ?

Comment: Yes, now I get it, thanks for clarifying :-). I suppose this is a much greater undertaking than we both realized from the beginning. I would suggest you break down your project into smaller tasks. I see at least three main tasks which them selves need to be broken down in smaller workable tasks): 1) Create your database on the web server and populate it with some test data. 2) Create your web service. I would suggest a REST based such while it's easier and more light weight. Verify that the web service works as you want it to. 3) Write your Android application.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with Microsoft's products, hence I can't give you hands on help on how to create your database in Visual Studio (I assume you need it to be  MS SQL Server database, otherwise you wouldn't specify it so clearly). There must be tons of tutorials and "how-to's" out there, though.

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply !! I need to tell u that I am new to both Android and .NET. I have just executed a few basic tutorials in both of them and this is my first major project u can say. Your 1) point suggests I should create a database on web server..can me tell me how to do that any tutorial that works for creating SQL database in VS2008 ..ur 2) point ..where should I create the REST web service ..in .NET itself ? To verify means to run the web service on my pc first right ? I guess we'll talk abt the Android code later...Thanks and please help me ..i would be very grateful :-) :-)

Comment: 1) I guess your favourite search engine (google, bing, ...) is one of your best friends here. You could try searching for "Visual Studio 2008 sql tutorial" or something. 2) If you need to stick to Microsoft's .NET infrastructure I guess you'd write it in .NET, yes (note that REST is just a concept, not a technology) otherwise PHP is a rather easy server-side scripting language which is also supported by most web hosts. And yes, to verify the web service would be to test it on your computer by manually entering your REST-url's and verify that the returned JSON or XML is the expected :-)

Comment: Ok fine will do that ..Just one last thing is it possible to retrieve the entries from my database in a kind of ListView on my phone with checkbox buttons so that  user can multi select each one ? Also can I call another activity (say Activity2.java which is for calling the web service )from Activity1.java using the submit button ?

Comment: @dbm let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1798/discussion-between-parth-90-and-dbm)

Comment: Sorry I had to leave for a meeting. If you're not too angry we can continue the discussion in the chat-room you created (I'll have a peek every now and then, when I have some time to spare :-) )